# Push data from Golang to OpenTSTB

Tags: go, lang

I have stored the last one hour data into file. So I've to upload the previous data to openTSTB.

So, the code is as follows:

```
go func() {
        file, err := os.Open("/var/lib/agent/agent.db")

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err, "Err")
        }

        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

        for scanner.Scan() {
            arr := []byte(scanner.Text())
            url := "http://192.168.2.40:4242/api/put"
            req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(arr))
            req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "")
            client := &http.Client{}
            resp, err := client.Do(req)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()

        }
    }()
```

The above code pushes the last one hour data to openTSTB.

Current data is also pushed to openTSTB using another GoRoutine.

The code is as follows:

```
// Regular run
go func() {
    timeStamp, _ := strconv.ParseInt(strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().UnixNano()/1e9, 10), 10, 64)
    err := opentsdb.Put(
        MetricName,
        4,
        timeStamp,
        opentsdb.Tag{"host", hostname},
    )
}()
```

The problem is if last record is 4, my previous record has been uploaded with the old data [Ex: 4+4].

If I run single GoRoutine, it is working correctly. If I go with old and current data, the result is wrong.

How to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.